# Does javascript have any alternatives usable in tor?

Tags: javascript, tor

I would want to make a website in tor, and in tor most users probably choose to disable javascript. i was just wondering if there are any javascript alternatives?

Comment: NO [filler ...]

Comment: The list of available programming languages common to modern browsers includes one language.

Comment: CSS is pretty powerful, depending on what you meant to do with the JS…

Comment: @Pointy what about webassembly? (But yes, that requires JS to start, and would obviously be turned off as well)

Comment: Will your users trust you? You can ask them to allow javascript on your page to enable certain features.

Comment: @Bergi there was an entertaining Strange Loop presentation last year about how CSS really is a genuine programming language :)

Comment: Oh yea, web assembly; well if I were a person who wanted to keep JavaScript switched off I would be intensely surprised and irritated if the browser continued to run wasm, especially given some statistics I've seen that show that a very popular application for it is stuff like bitcoin mining.

Comment: Obviously it depends on what you need to do, but it is possible to do whatever processing you need to do on the server and return it as static HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any site that is designed for tor has to account for user preferences. Any client-side language will come with potential vulnerabilities. As such, no.